# selenium webdriver with google chrome - chrome profile cookies

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction here.  I'm having a little trouble using webdriver with chrome profile cookies.

I have the following block of code that I include in my setup method.  This setup method also includes various chrome options that I need to run before all my unit tests.  I call this setup method from within all my unit tests.

I need this code to ensure that my profile cookies are deleted before the tests begin.  The trouble is, I only need to call it once - before my run of tests and not before every single test.  As a result, if I run a single unit test, it works fine but if I try to run 2 or more tests together, I get error messages that my chrome cookie path is being used by another process

```
public ChromeSetup()

        {
                string ChromeProfileCookies = (@"X:\Profiles\Chrome\Profile1\Default\Cookies");

                File.Delete(ChromeProfileCookies); 
        }
```

I hope that makes sense?  Would anyone be so kind as to explain how I can resolve this?

Comment: You can find detailed explanation in Selenium WebDriver documentation. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp In this page find a section "Cookies".

Comment: Thanks for trying but that's not really helpful to me